# Xlsxwriter hide data series in scatter plot

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have used xlsxwriter to add various different data series (lines) to a plot. What I would like to do now is disable certain series by default but, still have the disabled series available to reenable when looking at the graph.

For example, in the following image, while xlsxwriter adds all the series as I want it to, I would also like to not show "Sample2" & "Sample3" while showing "Sample1" by default.

The only feature I have been able to find that does something similar would be the:

```
# Delete/hide series index 0 and 2 from the legend.
  chart.set_legend({'delete_series': [0, 2]})
```

It appears to "delete" it more than hide it because if I try to toggle them back on they don't show up.
Maybe it's not possible through xlsxwriter but is there any other way I can implement this functionality?

[image]

Comment: That feature of "chart filters" is a recent addition to Excel and isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're enjoying your stay here lmao.

## Delete/hide series index 0 and 2 from the legend.

chart.set_legend({'delete_series': [0, 2]})
This work?
If not...
for Mac:
Click on the chart.

On the ribbon, click Chart Design and then click Select Data.

On the Chart Design tab, click Select Data
This selects the data range of the chart and displays the Select Data Source dialog box.

To edit a legend series, in the Legend entries (series) box, click the series you want to change. Then, edit the Name and Y values boxes to make any changes.

To rearrange a legend series, in the Legend entries (series) box, click the series you want to change and then select the alternate text or alternate text arrows.

Windows:

Right-click your chart, and then choose Select Data.
n the Legend Entries (Series) box, click the series you want to change.

Click Edit, make your changes, and click OK.

Changes you make may break links to the source data on the worksheet.

To rearrange a series, select it, and then click Move Up alternate text or Move Down alternate text.

You can also add a data series or remove them in this dialog box by clicking Add or Remove. Removing a data series deletes it from the chart—you can’t use chart filters to show it again.

If you want to rename a data series, see Rename a data series.

I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I don't think this is quite what I am looking for. I would like to do this without any direct user manipulation of the graphs.